# PHP-Object-Oriented: The property is assigned even though it is not declared in the object definition

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Store
{
}

$obj1 = new Store() ;

$obj1 -> storeName = 'Book Store' ;

echo $obj1 -> storeName ;

?>
```

When I execute this php script it gives the output as `Book Store`.

Shouldn't an error be triggered saying that the property is undefined?

What exactly is happening and why?

Comment: With assigning the value to the property you create it with the visibility public.

Comment: So, can I declare it externally?

Comment: Yes, but it will be by default public

Comment: It's defined as an variable. If you comment `$obj1 -> storeName = 'Book Store' ;` it will give you this error: `Notice: Undefined property: Store::$storeName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach new properties to your objects at any time from anywhere. Objects aren't "write protected" or anything like that. Properties such attached have a visibility of `public`.

A trivial example of that is `stdClass`; setting values on such an object is only possible through this mechanism, otherwise `stdClass` would be entirely useless:

```
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->bar = 'baz';
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks! I also have two doubts related to this. 1. Isn't the new property `$bar` confined only to the instance of the class `$foo`? i.e. if I create a new instance of the class, say, `$obj2`, it doesn't contain `$bar`. 2. Why does this concept exist and how can it be practically applied?

Comment: 1. Yes, the property will only exist on the specific object you add it to; it won't suddenly appear at class level. 2. Many object oriented languages work this way, where objects are more or less just key-value maps. Whether you should actually do this in practice or not is very debatable; I'd declare all properties I expect to work with at class level and not willy nilly declare new properties at runtime.

Comment: Oh, now the concept is clear to me. Your explanations are very valuable. Thanks! :)